# andengine - Convert entity coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: android, coordinates, andengine

How can I know the screen coordinates of my entity? I've come with the solution:

```
float x = (mainEntity.getX() - camera.getSurfaceX()) / screenRatioX;
float y = (mainEntity.getY() - camera.getSurfaceY()) / screenRatioY;
```

which works fine until I rotate my camera. Is there any straightforward way to get this?

Comment: Do you mean sprite.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(x,y)?

Comment: Sorry! Didn´t get any notifications about your comment... Actually I need to know the position of the Sprite on the screen, not on the scene. What does "Local" means in Andengine?

Answer (score 1):

```
float[] cameraSceneCoordinates = 
             camera.getCameraSceneCoordinatesFromSceneCoordinates(mainEntity.getX(),
                                                                  mainEntity.getY());
```

Comment: In the future, be sure to provide an explanation with your answer.